# Bookdown add URL as footnote

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I am having problems getting correct pdf output of figure legends that contain a url. It works as `bookdown::gitbook` but not as `bookdown::pdf_book`

Here is an example:

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_book
---

## Reference with URL doesn't work
In this experiment, we will use a [spectrophotometer]     (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophotometry) to measure the absorption of light of different wavelength by colored solutions.

(ref:spectrum) [Spectrum of light. V, violet; B, blue; G, green Y, yellow; O,   orange; R, red](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Linear_visible_spectrum.svg)

```{r spectrum, fig.cap='(ref:spectrum)', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE,     warning=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("./figures/photosynthesis/spectrum.png")
```

## Reference without URL does work
In this experiment, we will use a [spectrophotometer] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophotometry) to measure the absorption of light of different wavelength by colored solutions.

(ref:spectrumNOurl) Spectrum of light. V, violet; B, blue; G, green Y, yellow; O, orange; R, red.

```{r spectrumNOurl, fig.cap='(ref:spectrumNOurl)', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE,  warning=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("./figures/photosynthesis/spectrum.png")
```
````

What I want is the figure legend appearing like in the example without url but with a superscript to the url in a footnote.

---

**Additional Information**

I am using bookdown (0.7.8), rstudio (1.1.423) with Pandoc 2.1.3 on a docker container (rocker/rstudio) on OS X (10.13.5 Beta) on MacBook Pro 13.

I have tried everything I could but cannot solve this problem. I downgraded all Pandoc to the 1.x version that comes with bookdown but get the same problem. It doesn't matter whether I use pdflatex or xelatex as engine.

Comment: Hi Nikolaus, can you add in the YAML frontmatter the example is fully reproducible? I am unable to replicate the behaviour with my minimal example: https://gist.github.com/mikey-harper/1b3b63d19f0564546e4130bbb6beb538

Comment: Hi Mikey, when I use your example I get a different but also not the desired result: `Figure 2: [Spectrum of light. V, violet; B, blue; G, green Y, yellow; O, orange; R, red] `

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you edit the question including a full example similar to my link? It's impossible to help without this.

Comment: @Mikey I did as you requested and added a simple example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions here:

**1. Adding hyperlinks as footnotes**

By default, the output LaTeX document will not display the hyperlink. We can redefine how `href` works using LaTeX commands. You can add the following lines to either your `preamble.tex` or embed it directly with the header:

```
\let\oldhref\href 
  - \renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
```

Using this in the YAML header:

```
---
output: bookdown::pdf_book
header-includes:
  - \let\oldhref\href 
  - \renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
---
```

If you prefer saving it as a separate file (something I would recommend for larger projects) you can use:

```
header-includes: preamble.tex
```

**2. Text references not working in caption**

This issue is caused as text references appear not to be able to contain any special character including `_` and `-`.  I have raised this as another question as this seems a specific sub-issue of your problem: [Bookdown text references not working if URL contains special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098235/bookdown-text-references-not-working-if-url-contains-special-characters)

The easiest workaround to this seems to be shortening the URL using a service like [this](https://goo.gl/). It is free and the links don't expire.

---

Here is a partially working solution. Stackoverflow won't allow for URLs from google to be included so you will have to replace **Shortened URL** with your link.

````
---
output: bookdown::pdf_book
header-includes:
  - \let\oldhref\href 
  - \renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
---

The references work fine when not used within a text reference [Spectrum of light. V, violet; B, blue; G, green Y, yellow](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Linear_visible_spectrum.svg)

(ref:spectrum) [Spectrum of light. V, violet; B, blue; G, green Y, yellow](Shortened URL)

```{r spectrum, fig.cap='(ref:spectrum)', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

I say this is partially working though: as you can see, we now have the footnote for the URLs, but the footnote in the caption is not actually displayed in the footer!

I think your better bet would be to use a bibliography and reference the figure using a citation in [@ref]. Check here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/citations.html