# Bookdown text references not working if URL contains special characters

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

There is some inconsistent behaviour of text references in bookdown with URLs containing special characters such as `:` or `_`. Here are some demonstrations:

```
---
output: bookdown::pdf_book
---

(ref:good) [This Works](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki)

(ref:good)


(ref:bad) [This Does Not](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Linear_visible_spectrum.svg)

(ref:bad)


The link will work normally [like here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Linear_visible_spectrum.svg)
```

[image]

Is there a way to get text references to work if they contain special characters?

---

This behaviour was flagged in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990699/text-reference-containing-url-not-working-in-figure-caption), but the symbols were not directly identified as the key issues within the question. I wanted to make a focussed thread on SO before raising it as a potential issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not caused by special characters but the fact that the link was too long, so the line in LaTeX was wrapped by Pandoc by default:

```
(ref:bad)
\href{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Linear_visible_spectrum.svg}{This Does Not}
```

It should be considered as a bug of **bookdown**, but there is a workaround:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    pandoc_args: [--wrap=none]
```